# PHP Shopping Cart Quantity+Textbox Update Session Variables without Database

Tags: php, session-variables, shopping-cart

I need help on this problem I don't need database by the way. What I need is to add the Quantity and the Textbox value but how? I ain't got much idea. Please help, thank you.
Every time I'm executing `$qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$i] + $_GET['txtquant']` Im getting an error of:

`Undefined index of: txtquant`

This is my code for the update href(button)

```
if(isset($_GET["updates"]))
{ 
$i = $_GET["updates"];
$qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$i] + $_GET['txtquant']; //Here is the 
quantity+textbox also the error 

$_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = $amounts[$i] * $qty;
$_SESSION["cart"][$i] = $i;
$_SESSION["qty"][$i] = $qty;
```

}

And here is my form code of Cart

```
         $total = 0;

        foreach ( $_SESSION["cart"] as $i ) {
         ?>
         <tr>
         <td><?php echo( $products[$_SESSION["cart"][$i]] ); ?></td>
         <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
         <td><?php echo ( $_SESSION["qty"][$i]); ?></td>
         <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
         <td><?php echo( $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] ); ?></td>
         <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>

         <td><a href="?delete=<?php echo($i); ?>">Delete from cart</a>
         </td>
         <td><input type="text" name="txtquants" value="1"><a href="?
          updates=<?php echo($i); ?>">Update Cart</a></td>

         </tr>

         <?php
         $total = $total + $_SESSION["amounts"][$i];
         }
         $_SESSION["total"] = $total;
         ?>
         <tr>
         <td colspan="7">Total : <?php echo($total); ?></td>

         </tr>
```

Comment: maybe a spelling mistake but your input text name is txtquants and u r searching for txtquant in GET.

Comment: I edited it sir but nothing happens :( what i need is to sums upp txtquant and quantity for e.g --- QTY is 1 and the Textbox you input is 10 then the result will be 11